# Javascript macro to stop creating a sheet if name in list does not match raw data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Yesterday someone helped me create a macro which runs through names from a list (in a sheet called ('Suppliers) and creates a new sheet for each name (a duplicate of a sheet called 'Raw Data'). Column A on the new sheet is filtered by the name and the spreadsheet is also called the same name.

I now need to edit the macro to look at the names in the the list ('Suppliers') and compare it to Column A in 'Raw Data'. If the name is not in 'Raw Data', I do not need a new sheet to be created. I'm relatively new to coding and don't have the knowledge to create this.

I would like to insert this functionality into the following code:

```
function factory() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var supSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Suppliers');
    var supNames = supSheet.getRange(1, 1, supSheet.getLastRow(),
        1).getValues();
    supNames = supNames.map(function (el) {
        return el[0];
    });

    supNames.forEach(function (name, i) {
        doTheWork(ss, name, i, supNames);
    });
}

function doTheWork(ss, name, i, allNames) {
    if (!name || name.length == 0) return;

    ss.getSheetByName('Raw Data').activate();
    var nSheet = ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
    nSheet.setName(name);

    nSheet.getRange('A:L').activate();
    nSheet.getRange('A:L').createFilter();
    nSheet.getRange('A1').activate();

    var values = [''].concat(allNames);
    values.splice(i + 1, 1);
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
        .setHiddenValues(values)
        .build();

    nSheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(1, criteria);

    nSheet.getRange('G:G').activate();
    nSheet.getRange('C1').activate();
    nSheet.getFilter().sort(3, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your factory function to this.

```
function factory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var supSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Suppliers');
  var supNames = supSheet.getRange(1, 1, supSheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  supNames = supNames.map(function(el) {
    return el[0];
  });
  var rdSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Raw Data');
  var rdNames = rdSheet
    .getRange(1, 1, rdSheet.getLastRow(), 1)
    .getValues()
    .map(function(row) {
      return row[0];
    });
  supNames.forEach(function(name, i) {
    if (rdNames.indexOf(name) != -1) doTheWork(ss, name, i, supNames);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you again for responding! Unfortunately nothing deleted when I ran it.

Comment: it doesn't delete anything, just creates the sheets as before but only for names in raw data sheet

Comment: No, it created sheets for all names in the 'Suppliers' list even if they're not in the 'Raw Data' sheets which was what happened before. I think there needs to be a step before where the 'Suppliers' list is run against the 'Raw Data' list maybe?

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much! I couldn't have done any of this without you, really really appreciate it.